# Getting attribute with condition using XPath

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I am using `iReport 5.6.0` to generate a report with xml datasource .

I need to select the attribute date of a node that  have an attribute named Type with a value of `START`
Since I'm new to `iReport` and `XPath` , i can't find the right `XPath` query .

I've tried this , but it didn't work :

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/Document]]>
</queryString>
<field name="Date" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription>
        <![CDATA[Date/@Date[@type="START"]]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Here 's my XML data file :

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Date Type="INV" Date="20140601" />
    <Date Type="START" Date="20140201" />
</Document>
```

(I need the value : `20140201` to be displayed)

Comment: If the element tag name must be *Date* and you don't mind the place of the document the element could be located in you could use `//Date[@Type='START']/@Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the XPath expression you're looking for:

```
Date[@Type="START"]/@Date
```

In natural language: get the `Date` attribute from `Date` elements that have a `Type` attribute with value "START".